# Python nameerror: name weight not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a short code of a simple neural net:

```
T=input("enter T: ")

for i in range(int(T)):
    N=input("enter N: ")
    minX=input("enter minX: ")
    maxX=input("enter maxX: ")
    for j in range(int(N)):
        weight[j]=input("enter weight: ")
        bias[j]=input("enter bias: ")
    x=minX
    nonspammer=0
    spammer=0
    for k in range(maxX-minX+1):
        for l in range(N):
            x=x*w[l]+b[l]
        if x%2==0:
            nonspammer+=1
        else:
            spammer+=1
        x+=1
    print(nonspammer,spammer,sep=" ")
```

This code is giving me the error:

> Nameerror: name weight not defined

Could someone help me find out the reason for this error? I'm a beginner to coding in python.

Comment: You never defined `weight` or `bias`.  In your for loop it is trying to index both of those variables, but neither exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

Before `for j in range(int(N)):` add the lines

```
weight=[0 for i in range(N)]
bias=[0 for i in range(N)]
```

You are trying to access elements of these lists even before declaring them to be lists

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the index of a non-exiting list, so you have to create first like :

```
for i in range(int(T)):
    N=input("enter N: ")
    minX=input("enter minX: ")
    maxX=input("enter maxX: ")
    weight=[0]*int(N)
    bias=[0]*int(N)
    for j in range(int(N)):
        weight[j]=input("enter weight: ")
        bias[j]=input("enter bias: ")
```

or create it empty and append it :

```
for i in range(int(T)):
    N=input("enter N: ")
    minX=input("enter minX: ")
    maxX=input("enter maxX: ")
    weight=[]
    bias=[]
    for j in range(int(N)):
        weight.append(input("enter weight: "))
        bias.append(input("enter bias: "))
```